# Add a semi transparent square in an excisting square using CSS3 and no extra DIV

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I currently have a simpel DIV square styled with CSS:

```
.redBlock {
    background-color: #e00808;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This generates a simpel red square.

Now I want to add a smaller semi transparent square in the center. In short I want something like this:

[image]

But without adding an extra DIV. How to do this (if possible)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how practical this is, but you can use an :after pseudo element.

http://jsfiddle.net/xgez0uaz/

#### HTML

```
<div class="test">

</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by ur question, I still don't see any difficulty here.

```
.redblock {width:150px;height:150px;border:5px solid #f00;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
```

u get a div with red around and transparent div in center.

Scenario changes, what you intend to do with that square?